# Пытаюсь конкатенировать(слепить) чары

Tags: c++, массивы, char

Почему не работает?

```
int main()
{

    char a[100] = "";
    int b = 5;
    char c = 'c';
    double k = 10.5;

    strcat(a, (char const*)c);
    strcat(a, " ");
    strcat(a, (char const*)b);
    strcat(a, " ");
    strcat(a, (char const*)b);

    std::cout << a << std::endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Потому что в с++ не следует использовать c-style cast.

Comment: А как жить с этим?

Comment: конструкция (char const*) не делает преобразований данных, только обманывает компилятор. функци strcat складывает си строки, а приложить число к строке она точно не может.

Comment: В данном случае никак. `с` не может служить аргументом для функции `strcat`. даже если сохранить в `c` `\0` и передать указатель, то такой вызов будет бесполезен. Так что надо использовать другой метод.

Answer (score 0):

От того, что вы напишете `(леопард)поросенок`, поросенок никого не покусает :)

То, что вы хотите сделать, можно сделать, например, так:

```
sprintf(a + strlen(a),"%d",b);
sprintf(a + strlen(a),"%с",с);
sprintf(a + strlen(a),"%lf",d);
```

Есть и другие варианты. Но лучше бы знать исходную задачу, чтоб не советовать, как именно держать отвертку при забивании ею гвоздей :)

Comment: странно советовать `sprintf` в 2018

Comment: Ну у меня есть класс у которого есть разные член-данные, мне надо сделать функцию, которая вернет char*. Вернуть она должна описание всех стоимостей член-данных. Тип класс у нас Phone, и функция должна вернуть строковый тип в котором написаны все характеристики нашего телефона.

Comment: Что значит "стоимость член-данных"? Вобщем, я бы вам в любом случае посоветовал работать со `string`...

Comment: Нам на курсе запрещают string. Вот и приходиться его избегать.

Comment: @Dim Если за эти курсы вы заплатили, то требуйте возврата средств.

Comment: @VTT, нет, это ВУЗ. ^_^

Comment: Воспользуйтесь один раз `sprintf` типа `sprintf(a,"Type: %s, cost: %lf, name: %s, age: %d", str, cost, "name", 10);`